# How to set up Django Azure website to access database

Tags: django, azure, django-pyodbc-azure

I am trying to set up my Django site using Azure Websites (not an Azure VM). I got a site with some static pages up and running, and I created an Azure SQL Database, but how do I connect the Django site to use the Azure db?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [django-pyodbc-azure](https://github.com/michiya/django-pyodbc-azure)

> django-pyodbc-azure is a refined fork of [django-pyodbc](https://github.com/avidal/django-pyodbc), a Django
>   MS SQL Server external DB backend that uses ODBC by employing the
>   [pyodbc](https://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/) library. It supports MS SQL Server and Windows Azure SQL
>   Database.

Features

- Supports Django 1.9.6
- Supports Microsoft SQL Server 2005, 2008/2008R2, 2012, 2014, 2016 and **Azure SQL Database**
- Supports LIMIT+OFFSET and offset w/o LIMIT emulation.
- Passes most of the tests of the Django test suite.
- Compatible with SQL Server , SQL Server Native Client , Micosoft ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server on Windows and FreeTDS ODBC drivers.

Answer (score 0):

I understand you can use something like the following in your `settings.py` file

```
DATABASES = {
  'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
    'NAME': os.environ['DBNAME'],
    'HOST': hostname + ".postgres.database.azure.com",
    'USER': os.environ['DBUSER'] + "@" + hostname,
    'PASSWORD': os.environ['DBPASS'] 
  }
}
```